# Magento 1 schema markup

Tags: schema, magento-1.7, schema.org

Need a little help. Can anyone guide me on how to add schema mark-up code to magento 1 website? I tried to search it on YouTube but didn't find anything helping

Schema type : Product
Website niche: E-commerce

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure I don't have to tell you that Magento 1 is now officially deprecated since over a year now, but I do just in case!

To add tags from schema.org, you need to add the proper tags in the .phtml files copied into yout theme directory as you shouldn't edit core files. The templates usually copied are these ones:

- app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
- app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml
- app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml
- app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/catalog/product/price.phtml

But maybe some other templates are to be edited in your theme, depending on how the theme is set up.

Then, edit each .phtml files to add the necessary tags that you need. Save the files and empty Magento cache, as well as your browser cache.

You can test the work done using Google's structured data testing tool (https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/).

This guy here has a good tutorial on how to do it: https://www.groovecommerce.com/ecommerce-blog/developers-toolbox-adding-rich-snippets-to-magento-products-with-schema-org-tags/